# PHP mail function requirements

Tags: php, postfix-mta

I am reading this from the PHP documentation:

Requirements
For the Mail functions to be available, PHP must have access to the sendmail binary on your system during compile time. If you use another mail program, such as qmail or postfix, be sure to use the appropriate sendmail wrappers that come with them. PHP will first look for sendmail in your PATH, and then in the following: /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/etc:/etc:/usr/ucblib:/usr/lib. It's highly recommended to have sendmail available from your PATH. Also, the user that compiled PHP must have permission to access the sendmail binary.

My question is what is this sendmail wrapper for POSTFIX that they are talking about? Usually when I install POSTFIX with yum install the mail function just starts sending mail? Is there something more to it than that?

Thank in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you don't need to do anything more.Just try a sample mail script like this.If it doesn't work then add `sendmail_path = /etc/postfix` in your `php.ini`.

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: How is /etc/postfix different from /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix?

Comment: I'm looking in main.cf and I see sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix. Is it not that path that needs to be added to php.ini?

Comment: You should first execute that code.If there is any error, post the error here.we can find solution

Comment: OK. I'm just saying my working server has a sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i in php.ini. So that must be the compatible MTA?

Comment: yes.I checked some forums ` /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i ` worked for some people.So try it